# Laravel Model Query with "with" and "where condition" not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This Query Of get bookmarks is working with condition without relation with user_topics

```
$bookmarkedposts = BookmarkedPost::where('leader_id',$user_id)->get();
```

But When I add add relation to other model it didn't work

```
$bookmarkedposts = BookmarkedPost::where('leader_id',$user_id)->with('user_topics.first_media')->get();
```

Here is Bookmarked.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookmarkedPost extends Model
{
   public function user_topics()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserTopic','id')->where('isdelete',0)->where('isactive',1);
    }
}
```

[bookmarked_posts_table_sturucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JNRN.png)
[user_topics_table_stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIIH7.png)

Comment: Can you show us the model `BookmarkedPost.php`

Comment: Yes, I have Added In Description. @YJRB , Please Help me.

Comment: "it didn't work" - What do you mean by that? Using `->with()` doesn't exactly do anything on its own... What is your expected result, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BookmarkedPost Model:

```php
class BookmarkedPost extends Model
{
   public function user_topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserTopic','user_topic_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

UserTopic Model:

```php
class UserTopic extends Model
{
   public function bookmarder_posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\BookmarkedPost','user_topic_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Inside the function now you can use:

```php
$bookmarkedposts = BookmarkedPost::where('leader_id',$user_id)->with('user_topic')->get();
```

Comment: Hello @AlbertoSinigaglia ,thank you so much for answer, I changed my Bookmarked.php exact as you wrote,but issue is still the same. :(

Comment: what relations have BookmarkedPost with UserTopics?

Comment: belongsTo here is method code
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\BookmarkedPost');

Comment: i mean, the relation in the database

Comment: In Database Bookmarked_posts table has column user_topic_id reference key of user_topic table.

Comment: @PremThakkar if the relation is  a one to many, but there is only one record where isdelete=0 and isactive=1, it's still a one to many, so in the user_topics method, you should use `->hasMany('App\UserTopic', 'foreign key of this table', 'primary key of this table')`

Comment: Thank You :), I used has many in bookmarked.php also but still getting the same result :( .

Comment: @PremThakkar can you please post the tables structure? about UserTopic and BookmarkedPost

Comment: Sure,I have added Images link end of description.

Comment: inside the user topic table, which field is the foreign key for Bookmarked table?

Comment: In bookmarked_posts table user_topic_id is foreign key for user_topics table.

Comment: so a BookmarkedPost has only one UserTopic, and one UserTopic has many BookMarkedPost right?

Comment: Yes That is Right.

Comment: and so you want the BookmarkedPost with leader_id = whatyouwant, each one with it's own UserTopic right? @PremThakkar

Comment: Yes, Basically User Topic is posts table and bookmarks is saved posts table where users/leaders can save any users/leaders posts.I want Records that saved by Logged in user's/leader's id.

Comment: @PremThakkar i will edit the answer in order to make the code readable

Comment: Thank You sooo much for helping me !! It means a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 BookmarkedPost::where('leade_id', $user_id)->with('user_topics');
```

Comment: Thank You so much for help but,I tried this This is also Not Working @YJRB

Comment: @Y JRB Getting no error but condition is not working.

Comment: Try to change your `user_topics()` relation like this : `return $this->hasOne('App\UserTopic', 'user_topic_id')->where('isdelete',0)->where('isactive',1);`

Comment: Already Tried That also But Still Condition is not working. :(

Comment: Does your code exists on Github and is open source?